# WPF Treeview with Buttons only near to the selected item

Tags: wpf, templates, treeview, wpf-controls

i searched for hours for a way to solve my problem but didn't get near to the solution.

I Want something like the Detail View of a Data Grid, but at a TreeView. So if i select an item of the TreeView i want to show three Buttons near the current selected item.

- Level 0

  - Level 1

    - Selected item [button1] [button2] [button3]

      - Level 4
      - Level 4

I tried multiple ways:

- Special HierarchicalDataTemplate
- Visual States
- ... 4hours

But nothing solved it. Is there a way in XAML to do this?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/146423/503501)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for this link

> jberger

While following your link I find two solutions that will fit my requirements:

[Listbox Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected/146423#146423)

[TreeView Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123608/change-treeviewitem-template-when-isselected-and-two-types-using-in-treeview)